# Combining three classes to get rid of redundancy

Tags: java, android

I have a screen that looks like this:
[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SxXA.png)

This is based off of this code:

```
public class PowersScreen extends Screen {

public PowersScreen(Game game) {
    super(game);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

public static int choice1 = 3;

int canvasW = g.canvasWidth();
int canvasH = g.canvasHeight();
Point centerOfCanvas = new Point(canvasW / 2, canvasH / 2);
int rectW = 100;
int rectH = 100;
int left = centerOfCanvas.x - (rectW / 2);
int top = centerOfCanvas.y - (rectH / 2);
int right = centerOfCanvas.x + (rectW / 2);
int bottom = centerOfCanvas.y + (rectH / 2);

static Image chosen_one;

static String chosen_text = "hi";

int left_side_popcornX = g.canvasWidth() / 4 - (Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth() / 2);
int right_side_popcornX = 3 * g.canvasWidth() / 4 - (Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth() / 2);

static String back = App.getContext().getString(R.string.back);
static String next = App.getContext().getString(R.string.next);
static String choose_pwrup_1 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.choose_pwrup_1);
static String pwr1 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.power1);
static String pwr2 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.power2);
static String pwr3 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.power3);
static String pwr4 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.power4);
static String pwr5 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.power5);
static String pwr6 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.power6);
static String pwr7 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.power7);
static String pwr8 = App.getContext().getString(R.string.power8);

Rect rect1 = new Rect(0, 0, g.canvasWidth(), g.canvasHeight() / 8);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(left, top+100, right, bottom+100);
Rect rect3 = new Rect(left, top-100, right, bottom-100);
Rect info = new Rect(left_side_popcornX-10, (6 * g.canvasHeight() / 8), right_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth() + 10, (7 * g.canvasHeight() / 8));

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

       int x2 = event.x;
       int y2 = event.y;

       if (rect2.contains(x2, y2)) {
           game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
       }

       if (rect3.contains(x2, y2)) {
           game.setScreen(new PowersScreen2(game));
       }

       if (x2 >= left_side_popcornX && x2 < (left_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth())
               && y2 >= 2 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 && y2 < (2 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 + Assets.happyPopcorn.getHeight())) {
           //first popcorn
           choice1 = 3;
       }

       if (x2 >= left_side_popcornX && x2 < (left_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth())
               && y2 >= 3 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 && y2 < (3 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 + Assets.happyPopcorn.getHeight())) {
           //second popcorn
           choice1 = 6;
       }
       if (x2 >= left_side_popcornX && x2 < (left_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth())
               && y2 >= 4 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 && y2 < (4 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 + Assets.happyPopcorn.getHeight())) {
           //third popcorn
           choice1 = 9;
       }
       if (x2 >= left_side_popcornX && x2 < (left_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth())
               && y2 >= 5 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 && y2 < (5 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 + Assets.happyPopcorn.getHeight())) {
           //fourth popcorn
           choice1 = 12;
       }
       if (x2 >= right_side_popcornX && x2 < (right_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth())
               && y2 >= 2 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 && y2 < (2 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 + Assets.happyPopcorn.getHeight())) {
           //sixth popcorn
           choice1 = 15;
       }
       if (x2 >= right_side_popcornX && x2 < (right_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth())
               && y2 >= 3 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 && y2 < (3 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 + Assets.happyPopcorn.getHeight())) {
           //seventh popcorn
           choice1 = 18;
       }
       if (x2 >= right_side_popcornX && x2 < (right_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth())
               && y2 >= 4 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 && y2 < (4 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 + Assets.happyPopcorn.getHeight())) {
           //eighth popcorn
           choice1 = 21;
       }
       if (x2 >= right_side_popcornX && x2 < (right_side_popcornX + Assets.happyPopcorn.getWidth())
               && y2 >= 5 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 && y2 < (5 * g.canvasHeight() / 8 + Assets.happyPopcorn.getHeight())) {
           //ninth popcorn
           choice1 = 24;
       }                    
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(float deltaTime) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint.setTypeface(Assets.myFont);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    g.clearScreen(Color.rgb(51, 51, 255));

    g.drawRectText(choose_pwrup_1, rect1, paint);
    g.drawImage(PowersScreen.getDecodedChoice(), (g.canvasWidth() / 2) - (CustomizeScreen.getDecodedChoice().getWidth() / 2), g.canvasHeight() / 8);
    g.drawRectText(back, rect2, paint);
    g.drawRectText(next, rect3, paint);

    g.drawRectText(chosen_text, info, paint);
    g.drawRect(info, paint);

    g.drawImage(Assets.powerup_speedup, left_side_popcornX, 2 * g.canvasHeight() / 8);
    g.drawImage(Assets.powerup_stopall, left_side_popcornX, 3 * g.canvasHeight() / 8);
    g.drawImage(Assets.powerup_clearall, left_side_popcornX, 4 * g.canvasHeight() / 8);
    g.drawImage(Assets.powerup_doublepoints, left_side_popcornX, 5 * g.canvasHeight() / 8);
    g.drawImage(Assets.powerup_regainheart, right_side_popcornX, 2 * g.canvasHeight() / 8);
    g.drawImage(Assets.powerup_nolostheart, right_side_popcornX, 3 * g.canvasHeight() / 8);
    g.drawImage(Assets.powerup_nobadpopcorn, right_side_popcornX, 4 * g.canvasHeight() / 8);
    g.drawImage(Assets.powerup_stopboss, right_side_popcornX, 5 * g.canvasHeight() / 8);
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void backButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    game.setScreen(new PowersExplainScreen(game));
}

public static Image getDecodedChoice() {
    if (choice1 == 3) {
        chosen_one = Assets.powerup_speedup;
        chosen_text = pwr1;
    }
    if (choice1 == 6) {
        chosen_one = Assets.powerup_stopall;
        chosen_text = pwr2;
    }
    if (choice1 == 9) {
        chosen_one = Assets.powerup_clearall;
        chosen_text = pwr3;
    }
    if (choice1 == 12) {
        chosen_one = Assets.powerup_doublepoints;
        chosen_text = pwr4;
    }
    if (choice1 == 15) {
        chosen_one = Assets.powerup_regainheart;
        chosen_text = pwr5;
    }
    if (choice1 == 18) {
        chosen_one = Assets.powerup_nolostheart;
        chosen_text = pwr6;
    }
    if (choice1 == 21) {
        chosen_one = Assets.powerup_nobadpopcorn;
        chosen_text = pwr7;
    }
    if (choice1 == 24) {
        chosen_one = Assets.powerup_stopboss;
        chosen_text = pwr8;
    }
    return chosen_one;
}
}
```

What I want to do is have the user tap on a power up they want to use (with the description of that power up appearing at the bottom of the screen and their current choice at the top of the screen). Then be able to hit "Next" where they can choose their second power up and then their third power up. Each time they choose a power up, the option to choose that power up again should disappear (meaning the picture of that power up should go away). They should be also able to hit "Back" to reselect a previous power up.

I am accomplishing this now by having three different classes that handle each power up. The other two look exactly like this one except for the int choice options (the numbers have to be different so it knows which power up is being chosen). So, there is a lot of redundancy and it uses up space. I feel like this should all be able to be handled in one class. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

> The other two look exactly like this one except for the int choice options (the numbers have to be different so it knows which power up is being chosen).

You have a couple of options here.

---

One way to do it is to parameterize the "int choice" as something that is set when the class is created, and the class refers to it generically.

```
public class PowerupHandler {
    private int choice;
    public PowerupHandler(int choice) {
        this.choice = choice;
    }
}
```

---

Another way to do it is by creating an `abstract` class that does the same thing, but instead the subclasses just set the number in the constructor without any intervention

```
public abstract class PowerupHandlerAbstract {
    private int choice;
    public PowerupHandlerAbstract(int choice) {
        this.choice = choice;
    }
}
...
public class PowerupHandlerTypeOne extends PowerupHandlerAbstract {
    public PowerupHandlerTypeOne() {
        super(3);
    }
}
```

My personal preference (depending on the setup, of course) would be the abstract route, since it makes a little bit more sense to a skimming reader